# How can i find out time when my key is stored in Ignite Cache?

Tags: c#, ignite

I want to find out some of below question for Ignite Cache

1. when my key was updated last? Check if it's updated in the last 1 minute?
2. When the key was inserted in the cache?
3. TTL for key

Note: I am using the Cache expiration policy as the RAM + persistence file. So if not found in cache then it will go to the persistence file and if not found there then only go to the database(for e.g. SQL).

I am trying to achieve the above operation using C# thin client API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Ignite does not provide such public API.

There is an open Ignite ticket [7641](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7641) you may take a look into.

Also it's not clean why do you mix native and a 3rd party persistence.
Ignite will handle expiration by it's own with both in-memory and persisted storage.

You can take a look for a suitable configuration in a [documentation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/expiry-policies)